# How to write following code using list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I started learning list comprehensions recently. Here I'm trying to convert this code into list comprehension but unable to come up with.

```
def pairs_smaller1(lst):
  result =[]
  for element in range(len(lst)):
    temp = []
    value = lst[element]
    for value_for_comparison in range(len(lst)):
      if int(lst[value_for_comparison]) < value:
        temp.append(lst[value_for_comparison])
    result.append((value,temp))
  return result
```

Comment: Hey, what is the intended outcome of your code? I mean there are only a few places where you can use list comprehension. Can you be more specific

Comment: This is just an exercise that I was solving, so first I tried to solve it simple way to get the logic behind it. Now I want to do it using list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process in a bottom-up fashion:

```
def pairs_smaller1(lst):
  result =[]
  for element in range(len(lst)):
    temp = []
    value = lst[element]
    temp = [ lst[vfc] for vfc in range(len(lst)) if int(lst[vfc]) < value ]
    result.append((value,temp))
  return result
```

Then:

```
def pairs_smaller1(lst):
  return [(lst[e],[ lst[vfc] for vfc in range(len(lst)) if int(lst[vfc]) < lst[e]]) for e in range(len(lst))]
```

But this is very difficult to read and isn't more efficient, so it must be avoided.

Comment: Check there is a syntax error in code. There is an extra `)`. `temp = [ lst[vfc]) for vfc in range(len(lst)) if int(lst[vfc]) < value ]` should be changed by `temp = [ lst[vfc] for vfc in range(len(lst)) if int(lst[vfc]) < value ]`. Same applies for second code section.

Comment: Your code is throwing me syntax error which I'm fixing, what would be the efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks @CedricZoppolo ! It's fixed

Comment: Thanks @VictorDeleau I appreciate, just quick question. I was reading on one the post that the loops come in the same order in list comprehension, is that right?

Comment: @AsimKhan Yes I think it's true, otherwise this code wouldn't work. Outside first, inside last

Answer (score 2):

You could improve your code quite a bit by iterating directly on the values in your list, rather than using `range` to iterate over indexes:

```
def pairs_smaller1(lst):
  result =[]
  for x in lst:
    temp = []
    for y in lst:
      if int(y) < x:
        temp.append(y)
    result.append((x,temp))
  return result
```

Because that's so much more compact (not hurt by my choice of shorter variable names), you can pretty easily turn that into a couple of nested list comprehensions without compromising readability by much:

```
result = [(x, [y for y in lst if int(y) < x]) for x in lst]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.